# Google chrome strange blank UI

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Recently, if I minimize chrome and maximize this is what I get:

[image: Chrome blank UI screenshot]
The issue does not occur on every minimize+maximize. Only sometimes.
Beyond the point seen in screenshot, if I hover my mouse over blank area, UI elements under mouse get rendered.
If I switch to another program or open a new tab, UI immediately returns to normal.
What could be causing this issue?

And I don't think video driver is to blame because all other programs work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by resetting Chrome.
I don't know why it worked though because I have using that theme for 3 years. Perhaps something in latest versions of Chrome is incompatible with that theme.
None the less, this will hopefully work for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was having this problem as well. I went to Google for support, and they said that this is a known bug with the latest release of Google Chrome and that they are working to resolve it. If you are willing to wait it out until Google resolves the problem, then do so. I was told to reinstall Chrome, and if I was lucky, the problem would go away. It seems that I got lucky. I am sorry that I cannot provide you with more information. If you want to try an older version of Chrome if the reinstall doesn't help, [check this out](http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php).

Comment: I suspected it was a chrome issue. But Google is notorious (or proud) for no feedback from their end on reported issue.

Comment: Well, I have asked Google for help multiple times, and so far, I have had responses given each time.